# XSL - combine for each with text

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

Hi everybody i have a question concerning the for each loop.
I want to add a text sequence after any match. at the moment i am only getting the text and the whole matches. any idea why ?

This is my XML FIle, as example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
                <country>DE</country>
                <country>AUT</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

This is my XML Transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <xsl:value-of select="country" />
      <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Her here is my result and my Problem:

```
USA and
```

The expected output should be:

```
USA and DE and AUT
```

I am sure it is a beginner mistake and easy to solve, but i have no idea how to solve that in an easy way. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is one possible way :**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/country">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
          <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
              <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**<kbd>[`xsltransform demo`](http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6p)</kbd>**

**Brief explanations :**

- You can use dot (`.`) to reference current context element
- `&lt;` is encoded version of less-than sign character `<`
- The `xsl:for-each` part loops through `country` elements instead of `cd` as you initially did. And inside the loop it check if current `country` position index is less then (`<`) the last index, if it is then append text `" and "` to the value of `country`, otherwise only the value will be outputted.

Comment: thank you very much , this is what i was looking for